# update a column so duplicated values becomes unique

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Column `title` has a lot of duplicated values, more than once.

I need to update the column so, for example if `'gold'` is duplicated - it becomes `'gold 1'`, `'gold 2'`, etc.

Something like this:

```
$st = $db->query("select id, title from arts order by title asc");
$st->execute();
$x = 0;
while($row = $st->fetch()){
    $title = $row['title'];
    //if($title.is duplicated){
        $x++;
        $title .= ' ' . $x;
        $stb = $db->query("update arts set title = '" . $title . "' where id = " . $row['id']);
        $stb->execute();
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: What is `$db`? The `query` function for drivers I know doesn't use an `execute`.. this also looks to be open to SQL injections. You are only doing this for already existing data or new data? Maybe just append the ID of the column to the title? I think you don't need the `select` and can just do `update arts set title = concat(title, ' ', id) where title = 'gold'`

Comment: @user3783243, interesting idea, but it would be better alphabets only if a title is not duplicated.

Comment: Oh, I thought this was just for `gold`.  In that case maybe something like `update arts set title = concat(title, ' ', id) where title in (select title, count(*) as count from arts group by title having count >= 2)` (`having` syntax may be on the wrong side of `group` there, i mix it up because i use it rarely)

Comment: @user3783243, error - `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: Oh, yea the `count(*) as count ` makes that incorrect. Didn't think of that hmm, need some sort of non-capture syntax for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more efficient to do this in pure SQL rather than using PHP. Here is an approach that uses window functions, available in MySQL 8.0.

You can use a subquery to count how many `title` duplicates exists for each record, and assign a rank to each record within groups of records having the same `title`. Then, you can `JOIN` the subquery with the table to update. Where more than one record exists, you can append the row number to every record in the group.

Query:

```
UPDATE arts a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        title, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY title) cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY title ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM arts
) b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.title = CONCAT(a.title, b.rn)
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8pCqKWUNHHrgr7NAFcW5U3/1)**

Sample data:

```
| id  | title  |
| --- | ------ |
| 10  | silver |
| 20  | gold   |
| 30  | gold   |
| 40  | bronze |
| 50  | gold   |
| 60  | bronze |
```

Results after running the update query:

```
| id  | title   |
| --- | ------- |
| 10  | silver  |
| 20  | gold1   |
| 30  | gold2   |
| 40  | bronze1 |
| 50  | gold3   |
| 60  | bronze2 |
```

Comment: getting error on my localhost (xampp, windows, phpMyAdmin) - `... MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY title) cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY title ORDER BY' at line 6`

Comment: @qadenza: which version of MySQL/MariaDB are you using?

Comment: What I can see in `phpMyAdmin` (ver `4.8.5`) - Server type: `MariaDB`, Server version: `10.1.37-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution`, Protocol version: `10`

Comment: @qadenza I think he/she means `select @@version`

Comment: @user3783243, using `select @@version` result - `10.1.37-MariaDB`

Comment: @qadenza: in MariaDB, window functions are supported starting with version 10.2 only... So unless you upgrade, this solution will not work for your version of MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below code that working for me

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
// get all row  
$sql = "select id, title from arts order by title asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {   
    $title=$row['title'];
    // select where title is same
    $sql = "select * from arts where title='".$title."'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql);
    // if number of row is greater then one 
    if ($result2->num_rows > 1){
        $x=0;
        while ($row2=$result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id=$row2['id'];
            // skip first row 
            if($x>0){
                $newTitle=$title.' '.$x;
                $uquery = "update arts set title='".$newTitle."' where title='".$title."' and id=$id";                  
                $update = $conn->query($uquery);
            }
            $x++;
        }
    }   
}
```

[image: before query]

and after query run

[image: image below]

Answer (score 1):

This works in MySql 5.7:

```
update arts a inner join (
  select * from (
    select t.id,
      (
        select count(*) + 1 from arts 
        where id < t.id and title = t.title 
      ) counter
    from arts t
  ) t 
) t on t.id = a.id
set a.title = concat(a.title, ' ', t.counter)
where a.title in (
  select h.title from (
    select title from arts
    group by title
    having count(*) > 1    
  ) h 
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ty5oUWivPgnvTafbsrY3Zq/4).
For data:

```
| id  | title    |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | silver   |
| 2   | gold     |
| 3   | diamond  |
| 4   | bronze   |
| 5   | gold     |
| 6   | bronze   |
| 7   | gold     |
```

the result is

```
| id  | title    |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | silver   |
| 2   | gold 1   |
| 3   | diamond  |
| 4   | bronze 1 |
| 5   | gold 2   |
| 6   | bronze 2 |
| 7   | gold 3   |
```

Answer (score -1):

I think It would be more efficient to do this in SQL too, but you may can do a function to validate the duplicate, something like this:

```
function isDuplicated( $title, $db ){   
    $dp = $db->query("SELECT * FROM arts WHERE title = $title");        
    if ( $dp->num_rows > 1)
        return true;

    return false;            
}


$st = $db->query("select id, title from arts order by title asc");
$st->execute();
$x = 0;
while($row = $st->fetch()){
    $title = $row['title'];
    if( isDuplicated( $title, $db ) ){
        $x++;
        $title .= ' ' . $x;
        $stb = $db->query("update arts set title = '" . $title . "' where id = " . $row['id']);
        $stb->execute();
    }
}
```